# How to handle IDE project files with git-svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm using git-svn and there are IDE project files in the svn repository. Everytime I start my IDE it modifies project files a bit and they are marked as changed in the status display. And then if I try to do a git svn rebase to update my working tree to have the latest changes from the svn it fails as I have local modifications on the project files and I have to stash the changes. How can I ease my workflow so I wouldn't have to stash/stash apply everytime I haven't really modified anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a simple git alias which does what you want (*untested*):

```
[alias]
   safe-svn-rebase = "git stash 'preparing to rebase'; git svn rebase; git stash pop"
```

Comment: This seems to be the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Which IDE are you using? For instance with Visual Studio, there are .suo, and .csproj.user files that can be ignored by source control without causing you any headaches. The .csproj file will mainly change when you add or remove items so this should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain files it's probably a good idea not to add to source control. This is user specific stuff, and also quite often solution files. Project files are ok.